# Change Geany Terminal keybindings

Tags: shortcut-keys, geany, virtual-console

I would like to change the keybindings used in the vte terminal window in geany. For example, I would like to replace the current paste in terminal (ctrl-shift-v) by ctrl-v. How can that be done?